# How can I write an exception class with specific http status code in JAVA

Tags: java, exception

How can I throw an exception with specific http status? I want to generate the exception with 403 Forbidden status.
I used jax-rs library but it just change the message and the status code still got 500.

```
if (countRequest > 10) {
    throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN);
}
```

the output in postman:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1502582674498,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException",
    "message": "HTTP 403 Forbidden",
    "path": "/timesheets/late/61/cancel"
}
```

Comment: Your should show us what you have tried and what you have got?

Comment: Exceptions don't have a status. You are probably talking about `jax-rs` this is not something I should guess. Please try to ask more clear questions that show what you actually want, and what have you tried.

Comment: You can put whatever properties you want on a custom class you create.  What did you try and in what way does it "not work"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `ExceptionMapper` as below:

```
  @Provider 
  public class CustomExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<WebApplicationException> { 
      @Override public Response toResponse(WebApplicationException weException) { 
           // grab the response from exception
           Response response = weException.getResponse(); 
           // create error object/message as you like
           CustomError error = ...; 
           // return the custom error 
           return Response.status(response.getStatus()).entity(error).build(); 
       }
  }
```

You can refer [this](http://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jax-rs-jersey-custom-exceptions-handling-with-exceptionmapper/) tutorial for more detail use of `ExceptionMapper`.

Comment: tks @Rishikesh Darandale can you explain to me about CustomError? I confuse  about it.

Comment: @ThànhNguyễnDuy , `CustomError` will be your own class that holds the error information. If that does not helpful for you, then you can use your own implementation.

Comment: I tried it but I don't know why the exception doesn't match to the mapper class

Comment: Can you please share your web.xml or Jersey servlet configuration? Please share package name of the exception mapper class.

Comment: I use Gradle so all configuration is automatic, and name of exception mapper class is javax.ws.rs.